# LAN/WAN Combo Slot?

Tags: lan, modem, wan

My Modem has a slot that says "LAN/WAN", suggesting that it works for both. However, it already has a plug in the DSL slot. Thus, I assumed that the DSL slot actually functioned as the WAN.

Does that mean the DSL plug could also go into the LAN/WAN slot and still function properly?

Does it mean that I can actually have 2 WANs at the same time (the DSL connection going to CenturyLink, and the LAN/WAN slot going to another ISP)?

[image]

Comment: If you’re going to ask a question about a specific piece of equipment, it’s good to include the make, model, hardware revision, and firmware version of the device. Even just the make and model would be a huge help, so people can RTFM online for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That’s not just a DSL modem. It’s a combination box that includes a home gateway router, VOIP terminal, LAN-side 4-5 port Ethernet switch, and DSL modem. I wouldn’t be surprised if it’s also a Wi-Fi AP.

My guess, without knowing the brand and model number so I can RTFM online, is that the port in question acts as an Ethernet LAN port when the box is configured to use DSL for WAN, but it can switch it to being an Ethernet WAN port for when you already have some other modem to use it with.

That way if you upgrade from DSL to, say, fiber, you can just drop a fiber modem (ONT) in front of it and connect it to the Ethernet WAN port.

Comment: "That’s not just a DSL modem. It’s a combination box that includes a home gateway router, VOIP terminal, LAN-side 4-5 port Ethernet switch, and DSL modem. I wouldn’t be surprised if it’s also a Wi-Fi AP."
I'm aware of that, but is there a term for such a combination device? It would seem excessive to note all those details for every reference to it.
And thanks for the info!

Comment: @abcjme: "Home gateway", "Wireless router", "CPE" (customer premises equipment) are common ones, though not an exhaustive list. Calling it based on the _primary_ function (i.e. just "ADSL modem" or "wireless router" or "home router") is sometimes okay, depending on context. Personally I'd prefer the 1st one.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same thing and have the data sheet from my Zyxel C3000z and it says:

Gigabit Ethernet WAN / LAN Port
C3000Z includes a dedicated Gigabit Ethernet WAN Port. When CPE is operating
in DSL mode, this port will work as a 5th Gigabit LAN Port.

Comment: same modem I have, as pictured above.